# General purpose vomit response control?

Tags: medications, preventative-medicine, vomit

Is there a general purpose [antiemetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiemetic) for vomit response control?
Many vomit control solutions are focused on specific causes for the vomiting. Some common causes of nausea/vomiting:

- [Cancer treatments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancer_and_nausea#Management)
- Upset stomach/gastric distress
- Dehydration
- [Motion sickness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_sickness#Treatment)
- [Gastroenteritis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastroenteritis#Antiemetics)
- [Pregnancy](https://www.aafp.org/afp/2003/0701/p121.html)
- Alcohol

What I'm interested in is medicines or methods to suppress the vomit response in general, or at least cover a broad range of causes. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Physiology, Chemoreceptor Trigger Zone (StatPearls)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK537133/):

Nausea and vomiting are controlled by the **vomiting center** in the medulla oblongata, which is located between the brainstem and spinal cord. The main part of the vomiting center is the **chemoreceptor trigger zone (CTZ),** also known as the **area postrema (AP),** which receives signals from:

- the blood (uremia, ketoacidosis, hypoxia, opiates, cancer chemotherapy...)
- gastrointestinal tract (gastroenteritis or gastroparesis - signals travel via autonomic nerve fibers)
- the vestibular system (motion sickness, inner ear disorders)
- centers in the brain cortex and thalamus (pain, smells, psychological causes...)

[image]

Picture: Signals that induce vomiting (source: [Pharma Study World](http://pharmastudyworld.blogspot.com/2017/))

So, theoretically, there could be an antiemetic that would "block" the vomiting center and thus relieve nausea from any cause...

> ...yet, **there are no ideal and universal antiemetics available** in the
>   clinics because the existing antiemetics target only one or a few
>   stimuli that trigger the reflex. *([International Journal of Pharmacy and Pharmaceutical Sciences, 2019](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Nusieba_Ibrahim2/publication/332879729_Antiemetic_medications_Agents_current_research_and_future_directions/links/5cfec7eea6fdccd13091c236/Antiemetic-medications-Agents-current-research-and-future-directions.pdf))*

Anyway, certain antiemetics can be used to relieve nausea from more than one cause ([here: Table 2](http://file://nukovci/nukci/TSprofiles/rdp03/Downloads/Antiemetics.pdf)):

**Indications for antiemetics:**

1. 5-HT3 antagonists: ondansetron and palonosetron for chemotherapy-induced and posoperative nausea
2. D2 Antagonists:

   - Phenothiazines, such as prochlorperazine, for nausea associated with motion sickness, migraine, radiotherapy, chemotherapy, postoperative, viral gastroenteritis, and severe morning sickness during pregnancy
   - Butyrophenones, such as droperidol and olanzapine, for nausea associated with cancer chemotherapy and postoperative nausea associated with opioids.
3. H1 antagonists: promethazine and dimenhydramine for motion sickness and morning sickness in pregnancy
4. ACh (M) antagonists (anticholinergics): L-hyoscine as a transdermal patch for prophylaxis of motion sickness
5. Synthetic cannabinoids: dronabinol and nabilone for nausea associated with chemotherapy and radiotherapy in patients who have failed to respond to the other antiemetics
6. Corticosteroids: dexamethasone for chemotherapy-induced nausea and for severe morning sickness
7. SP/NK1 antagonists: aprepitant for postoperative and chemotherapy-induced nausea (in combination with dexamethasone)